# Use of the [extension] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Where should the [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension) tag be used?

Does it refer to browser extensions?

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/496451/how-to-start-chrome-with-only-some-extensions-selectively-enabled) has both [google-chrome-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions) and [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension) tags, and [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/485691/how-do-you-stop-firefox-from-opening-links-to-add-on-information-pages-after-eac) has both [firefox-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extensions) and [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension) tags.

Is there a unique use of the [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension) tag? Is it specifiaclly for Internet Explorer because there is no [internet-explorer-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-extensions) tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Update* – this is now completed. No more [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension).

I suggest we go through the [extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension) tag and disambiguate it.

- Move all browser-extension related questions to:

  - [google-chrome-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions)
  - [firefox-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extensions)
  - [safari-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safari-extensions)
  - *et cetera*
- Create [internet-explorer-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-extensions) in that process.
- Move all file extension questions to [file-extension](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-extension).

Anything that's left after cleanup should possibly have the tag removed, because if you're asking for extensions for *X*, it should be enough to just tag it *X*.

If there's enough agreement on that, let's go through that list and clean it up step by step.

Comment: There are also questions that refer to application extensions ([like this one](http://superuser.com/questions/463751/hacking-notepad-how-to-add-custom-commands-e-g-a-more-custom-timestamp-fea)) - I think that the application name tag would be sufficient. Also, what about generic browser extensions question, where the author doesn't ask about a specific browser ([like this question](http://superuser.com/questions/480804/play-sound-when-certain-text-appears-in-browser))?

Comment: Good question… I guess we could create `[browser-extension]` for that.

Comment: @slhck, and if that (I like that), do you then need the [browser-specific-extension] at all?  At that point you could get by with [browser-extension][firefox] and get the point across.

Comment: @Josh Interesting approach. Would never have thought about that. But on the other hand, combined tag searches are rarely used, plus the system makes it rather hard to follow tag combinations on-site, so I'd rather stick with tags that are specific enough on their own.

Comment: @slhck, gotcha.  For some reason I have this compulsion to have as few tags defined as possible :)  But I get what you're saying.

Comment: @Josh I think you have a point though. Today many extensions have a Chrome version and a Firefox version, and are not exclusive to Firefox as they used to be. I like the idea of [browser-extension][browser-name]. Many people look for a certain extension and they don't care if it's for FF or Chrome - but adding an additional general browser-extensions tag is not better than tagging this kind of questions with both [google-chrome-extensions] and [firefox-extensions] (which I don't think is good).

Comment: btw we have a [tag:browser-addons] for generic web browser extensions /cc @tempy

Comment: @Sathya [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/480804/play-sound-when-certain-text-appears-in-browser) is tagged with [browser][extension] instead of [browser-addons], for example. First of all, I think it should be renamed to [browser-extensions], because all the other extensions-related tags use "extension" and not "addon". Also, since there is already [browser-addons] tag then I think we should either remove the [extension] tag or rename it to [application-extension] (the only use I can think of for an extension that is not for a browser).

Comment: @tempy I created a synonym mapping from `[browser-extensions]` to `[browser-addons]`. If you want to help re-tag the remaining `[extension]` questions in smaller chunks, feel free to do so (but please if check the rest of the post needs improvements as well).

Comment: @slhck Okay. Can you also create [internet-explorer-extensions]? (for example, [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/496951/is-there-an-extension-like-its-all-text-for-internet-explorer) from just couple of days ago should be tagged with [internet-explorer-extensions] rather than [internet-explorer-9][extension].

Comment: @tempy Turns out, tag scan only have 25 characters. We therefore need to find an alternative… `[ie-extensions]` maybe?

Comment: @slhck Yeah, I think it's fine, `ie` is already a synonym of all the `[internet-explorer]` tags. Is it possible to make `[ie-extensions]` show up when typing `internet-explorer` (when tagging a question)?

Comment: @tempy Unfortunately no. The tag system isn't that clever. But I'll make it IE-extensions anyway. Better than nothing right?

Comment: @slhck Of course. Will you automatically re-tag [questions with `[browser-name][extension]`](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extension+google-chrome) to `[browser-name-extensions]`?

Comment: @tempy I'm afraid this is not possible with the tagging system either. We'll have to go through the tags manually. Already down from 72 to 57. We'd welcome any edit suggestions to remove those if you have the time to fix up these posts.

Comment: @slhck While going over the `[extension]` tag questions, I noticed there is a similar tag - `[addons]`, which is also useless (see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/417481/extensions-not-showing-on-extensions-tab-of-add-ons-manager-in-firefox-12)). After we will be done going over `[extension]` and `[addons]` we can probably delete both tags.

Comment: @tempy We can ask developers to remove tags when we've disambiguated them, yes. Would be a good idea.